# Bootstrap (data toggle) drop down menu on navbar not displaying as a block

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason when I click the pancake button, I have been able to get the menu to display as a block using the z-index but on the list of elements of the menu.  So the "block" is not the entire navbar but rather just the section that lists the links to the other pages and I ma not sure why.  I have tried to drill into css and use block elements with no luck.

Here is the html for the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">

<!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/hug/">Hug a Tree</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
        <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">about</a></li>

        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'favourites' %}" class="fav">f<span style="color:#e48666">a</span>vourites</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></li>


        {% else %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'register' %}">register</a></li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'login' %}">login</a></li>

        {% endif %}
    </ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

And the css:

```
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e9e7b6;
  margin: 25px;
  height: 100px;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-text {
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #5aa47d;

}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #5aa47d;

}
.navbar-default .navbar-link {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #5c606b;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-link:hover {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #5aa47d;
}

.navbar-toggle {
    margin-top: 33px;
}


ul.nav.navbar-nav.pull-right{
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
}


.nav.navbar-nav.pull-right li{
display: block;
z-index: 1;
background-color: #fff;
}

/*** navbar - icon ***/

img.brand {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }


/*** navbar - brand/logo ***/

.navbar-default .navbar-brand{
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  float: left;
  color: #426085;
  padding: 35px 15px 0px 25px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 25px
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover{
color: #5aa47d;

}



/*** navbar - list ***/

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #5c606b;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  color: #5aa47d;
}


.navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 39px;
        padding-right: 20px;
 }
```

Any insight would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qhtgj5dh/ tell me that are you seeing the toggle like this?

Comment: No - it looks like this:  http://postimg.org/image/4vpxa8ok1/

Comment: How is it supposed to look?

Comment: Hi.  I want it so when you press the pancake button a block spanning from the right border of the navbar to the left border of the navbar drops down. The links are perfect where they are, I just want them sitting on top of the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elektriheart/6zf9cdbf/)

`pull-right` was deprecated as of v3.1.0 and replaced with `navbar-right`.

Comment: You solved it!  Thank you so much.  I also had to put some z-index stuff for it to work since a lot of the page is generated by scripts (django/python) and so the layering is not static.  Here is the fix for people needing the same help `@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-nav > li > a {
        padding: 20px 30px 20px 0px;
        z-index: 999;
    }
}        navbar .navbar-collapse {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #5aa47d;
    margin: 25px 0px;
    text-align: right;
    border: none;
    z-index: 998;
    position: relative;
}`

Comment: So again thank you so much for taking the time to help me.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

**Alexis Jensen** Hi there.  You are using a class `pull-right` in this line of code...
`<ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">`

If you remove the `pull-right` class it will expand across.
Is that all you were wanting here?